# Why doesn't skip_on_empty work when migrating from a text field?

Tags: 8, users, migrations, plugins

I'm trying to migrate Drupal 7 users to Drupal 8.  In Drupal 7, there's an additional text field representing the user's group.  In Drupal 8, it's a taxonomy vocabulary.  So I'm using the following pipeline:

```
  field_user_group:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: field_directorate
    -      
      plugin: extract
      index:
        - 0
        - value
    -
      plugin: entity_generate
      value_key: name
      bundle_key: vid
      bundle: groups
      entity_type: taxonomy_term
      ignore_case: true
```

`field_directorate` is the source field in D7, and `field_user_group` is the target in D8.

Records without that value set should be caught by the `skip_on_empty` plugin, and left blank, but that plugin seems to be failing (letting the process continue to the next plugin in the pipeline) as I'm getting errors from the `extract` plugin saying:

> Array index missing, extraction failed.

According to [the documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21SkipOnEmpty.php/class/SkipOnEmpty),

> The skip_on_empty process plugin checks to see if the current input value is empty (empty string, NULL, FALSE, 0, '0', or **an empty array**). If so, the further processing of the property or the entire row (depending on the chosen method) is skipped and will not be migrated.

How is the processing even getting to `extract` if `skip_on_empty` is supposed to skip values with an empty array?

It works fine for records with the value set.

Comment: I'm still wondering why `skip_on_empty` doesn't work, but I was able to work around this by dropping that plugin entirely, and going directly to [extract](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21Extract.php/class/Extract).  You can specify a `default` parameter that gets used if there are missing keys.  I set it to the empty string '', and then there were no more failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now believe this to be caused by [Get process plugin sets multiple for empty array](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2905929).